# How to convert timestamp into human readable time string (for example "one minute ago") in Java

Tags: java, android, timestamp, relative-time-span

I am trying to create a chat application in android studio.
I have a timestamp, say this

```
1694603269045
```

Now I want to convert this timestamp into human readable way like `one minute ago` or `one hour ago`. I will is into my `storyView` mode where a user will be able to see when his friends uploaded a story/status.

I need this as `String`, like

```
one minute ago
```

so that I can use it in a `TextView`. Is that possible?

I tried to find some solutions but most of them are related to javascript where I need it in Java.
The `String` needs to be like this:
[image: Example]

Is that possible in Java in some way? Thank You.

Comment: Assuming that represents milliseconds since epoch, calculate the number of milliseconds from the timestamp to now, divide by 1000, you have seconds. Is it bigger than 60? Divide by 60 and you have minutes. Is it bigger than 60? Divide again by 60 and you have hours. Is it bigger than 24? Divide again by 24 and you have days. And so on...

Comment: Any solution in JS should be easily translatable to Java, or you can just code it yourself, doesn't seem very complicated as stated by @FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: That was more than one minute ago, but `Duration.between(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1694603269045L), Instant.now(Clock.systemUTC()));`

Comment: How does this Duration.between and Instant.now works?

Comment: Math. [`Duration.between(Temporal, Temporal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) and [`Instant.now(Clock)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now-java.time.Clock-)

Comment: How to get the string by the help of these?

Comment: Formatting this, specifically in English, may need you to manually arrange it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `Instant` from your *timestamp* and calculate the `Duration` between it and `Instant.now()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your timestamp   
    long timestamp = 1694603269045L;
    // convert to an Instant
    Instant then = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);
    // get "now"
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    // calulate the Duration
    Duration duration = Duration.between(then, now);
    // print the minutes part
    System.out.println(duration.toMinutesPart() + " minutes ago");
}
```

This just printed

```
47 minutes ago
```

You will have to check which values (hours, minutes, seconds and so on) are actually zero if you want to switch from minutes to hours when minutes are 0, but hours aren't, for example. This would print `0 minutes ago` in 13 minutes and you may want to cover situations like that.

Comment: It just said Usage of API documented as @since 9+ 

Call requires API level 31 (current min is 24): java.time.Duration#toSecondsPart

Comment: You can make those calls available by [`Android API Desugaring`](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table), I think…

Comment: Yeah, I did that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a third party library, you might want to take a look at [PrettyTime Library](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime)

Using PrettyTime your code could look as simple as:

```
String calculateTimeAgoWithPrettyTime(final Instant pastTime) {
    PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime();
    return prettyTime.format(pastTime);
}
```

Comment: I found the dependency but there is no code, what does it return?

Comment: [This JUnit test](https://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/#examples) shows examples of what it returns. Only don’t use the outdated `Date` class as those examples do. Use `Instant` as in this answer, or other classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.